# How can I beta test in Xcode with iOS 8?

Tags: xcode, ios8

I have the latest iOS8 Beta on my iPhone. (Beta 1) And want to start testing my apps with iOS8. But Xcode shows that the latest os is ios 7.1. How can I achieve this?

Comment: don't get you I `am afraid ... xcode5 doesn't work with ios8 sdk

Comment: You need to use Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install xCode6 to Beta test app on iOS8 Devices.

You download from members center.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

[image]